# 2 DataGridViews in one, overlapping with backcolor transparent

Tags: c#, events, datagridview, overlapping

I have a question about DataGridviews. I want to have 2 DGVs overlapping each others. The above DGV should be transparent so that i can see the values from DGV which is belov. Or how can i do that in one DGV with Event? or other ways to do it?

[image]